# 13in Battery Thinkpad/MacBook Pro

Tags: battery-life

I would like to install a battery pack on the bottom of 2017 13in MacBook Pro(I don't mind tapping it honestly).  Considering it charges by USB C I am hopefully this might not be to difficult.  I use my MacBook Pro while commuting but the battery doesn't last long enough.

If there isn't one of my Macbook Pro maybe my 13 Thinkpad?

Comment: Going to get an answer fleshed out tonight, did some research in the past on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## There's nothing you should get for your MacBook (right now)

In doing my research, I found just two solutions that sort of have what you want. Both also focus on including more I/O, not just the battery. My guess is for a product of this nature, they'll all do this.

#### [Linedock](https://www.linedock.co/) - $299

[image]

At 71.61 Wh–146% of the MacBook 13" built-in battery–this thing packs a pretty hefty punch. However, your wallet will also feel it. [Compared to other "dumb" battery banks with similar capacity](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MZ61PRW), it's a hefty price to pay. Sure, you get more I/O and (optionally) storage and a great form factor, but that's a lot of $$$. Note also that, while shaped like the MacBook, **it is not a case and does not sit flush with the MacBook**, and is much closer to a pad than a case.

Finally, note that this is an Indiegogo project, and so far, doesn't seem to have any reputable reviews or even confirmation of shipments as far as I can tell; it hasn't even finished shipping to backers. There's really no way I can recommend you buy this product at this stage.

#### [DEC](https://www.owcdigital.com/dec)

[image]

It's a beautiful product by a reputable manufacturer that basically does what the Linedock does, but better. Only issue: it really doesn't exist yet. There's no pricing, specs, or even delivery date. While [at least one prototype was created](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vUe2KAwvZsA), it did not include a battery. You can't preorder it, and there's no way I'd recommend you do.

#### Random battery banks?

Unfortunately, as far as I could find, there aren't any plain battery banks that are even close to the form factor of a MacBook. Even sites making recommendations specifically for the MacBook at best just end up recommending slim battery banks like [this Aukey model](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0759TDR3H), and unless you want to carry one separately rather than affixed to your device, I can't seriously recommend one.

Comment: If I can daisy chain two together maybe I could put 2 on the bottom of my laptop and put something else other places to fill it out.  I don't think the hinges on the thinkpad/macbookpros  are strong enough to hook it to the screen.  Linedock is definitely overpriced not to mention I am concerned how long it will last.

Comment: Although you could, there's really no way I can recommend that seriously. You could possibly do it with a 3D printed case and cable, but I don't know if that's something you'd be interested in.